# Angular page navigation in the side menu

Tags: html, angular-cli

I want to implement a page navigation in a side menu in my angular page like this.
[image: Angular official website page navigation]

But I couldn't find any like this component in the Angular Material or Bootstrap.

Is there any good library that offers a page navigation in a page side?

Or do I just need to write a code myself to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will take a look at the source you will see they are using `<aio-toc ng-version="8.1.0-next.1">`

When you will look for it you will see the source code over here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio/src/app/custom-elements/toc

Comment: Great!!. I could finally implement a navigation (toc) in my angular project using the component that you suggested. It worked!!. (It didn't work in stackblitz though)